# Why is SSIS job using connection manager parameters in package to validate instead of configuration file values?

Tags: sql-server, validation, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, configuration-files

I have an SSIS package that is run with a SQL Server Agent job with a configuration file specified in the job that contains the servers and initial catalogs for the connection managers of the package. It was running fine in production and using the servers and databases specified in the configuration file when the package runs. However, when I changed a table in the DEV environment, the PRODUCTION package FAILED validation because it is apparently validating the package based on the DEV database specified in the connection managers in the package (which naturally point to the DEV environment) and then using the config file values when actually running the package. This is ABSURD, of course. HOW do I stop it from doing that? It should both validate and run using config file parameters, otherwise what is the point of using config files?!

I should clarify that the PRODUCTION job RAN without problems after generating the errors internally, but I have an error handling task that emails me the details of any errors that the package raises during execution. Getting emails of failures for packages that didn't ACTUALLY encounter any errors when they ran is not a good thing.

I am using SSIS in SQL Server 2008 R2 and both the SSIS package and the XML configuration file are stored in the file system. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just set DelayValidation to true?

Comment: Delay Validation IS Set to TRUE for every task in the package and the package itself.

Comment: Are you directly configuring a Connection Manager or do you apply the strings to SSIS Variables when are then used in an Expression on your Connection Manager? Do you have a minimal reproduction that would show the problem?

Comment: The Connection Managers are directly configured. The values are changed in the configuration file for server name and initial catalog. Sorry, not sure how to reproduce usefully. Would using expressions in Connection Managers change the behavior and is this a best practice?